Intuition of compactness in function spaces
I understand compactness in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
However, I do not know much about what sets of function spaces are compact.
For example, what are the compact sets of the spaces $B([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ of bounded functions on $[0,1]$ with sup norm?
My attempt

Finite sets are compact.
For elements $f_1,...,f_n$ of $B([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ and intervals $[a_1,b_1],...,[a_n,b_n]$, $\{x_1f_1+\dots+f_n;\forall k x_k\in [a_k,b_k]\}$ is compact.


See p. 260 Of Dunford and Schwartz, Linear Opetaors. Vol.  1

What type of intuition are you looking for?  For instance, could you successfully answer your own question in the context of $\mathbb{R}^n$ without referencing general open/closed sets? (I'm not sure I'd be able to do so)  On the other hand, we can extend Heine-Borel to your example by generalizing it, if that's all you're wondering.
